# Cantor's Intersection Theorem with closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Cantor's Intersection Theorem states that "if $\{C_k\}$ is a sequence of non-empty, closed and bounded sets satisfying $C_1 \supset C_2 \supset C_3 \dots$, then $\bigcap_{n \ge 1} C_n$ is nonempty.

If the term "compact sets" is replaced by "closed sets", the statement is not true. It makes sense to me, but couldn't find such a counterexample for it.

Comment: If a counterexample exists, it'll have to make use of the difference between "closed" and "compact." This difference is boundedness.

Comment: You can create an ellipsis in MathJax by using `\dots`.

Comment: yah I noticed that the integer set is closed but unbounded, but not sure it is a valid example..@T.Bongers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence $C_n = [n, \infty)$.

Comment: why the intersection of these sets is empty? Is it because we can't find such a number in every set?

Comment: There is no real number which belongs to $C_n$ for every $n$, so the intersection is empty.